# Athena aggregate list struct string string to string list

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I have an aggregate array of type `array<struct<string,string>>` and I would to convert it to `array<struct<string,array<string>>>`

More precisely, I have a list like that

```
[{'a', 'b'}, {'a', 'c'}, {'d', 'e'}]
```

And I would like to aggregate it like

```
[{'a', ['b', 'c']}, {'d', ['e']}]
```

How can I convert it like that in Athena ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `multimap_from_entries` does exactly what you need.

See the [doc](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/map.html) of the function.

EDIT:

While aws decides to update presto :-), here's a workaround:

```
SELECT map_filter(reduce(array[cast(('a', 'b') AS row(one varchar, two varchar)),
               cast(('a', 'c') AS row(one varchar, two varchar)),
               cast(('d', 'e') AS row(one varchar, two varchar))],
              map(array[cast('' as varchar)], array[array[cast('' as varchar)]]), 
              (s,x)-> if(s[x.one] is null, map_concat(s,map(array[x.one], array[array[x.two]])),
                         map_concat(s,map(array[x.one], array[s[x.one] || array[x.two]])))
              , s->s), (k,v)->k <> '')
-- {a=[b, c], d=[e]}
```

The idea is to loop over the array and construct the map by either inserting a new key,value pair if the key is new, or extending the value-array with the new value.

Comment: I saw that but multimap are not implemented in Athena